# Change Sierra Login Screen Background Blur Amount

Tags: macos

Ever since the Sierra update, when I boot up my Mac the background is a lot less blurred and more saturated then the normal lockscreen.

I'd like to be able to customise the the amount of blur (not remove it entirely) and saturation on the lockscreen and I am wondering how I would be able to achieve this.

Boot Background (What I want the lock screen to look like as well):
[image: BootScreen]

Lock Screen (A lot more blurred and less saturated):
[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: It's a security feature in case your background is sensitive information.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to adjust it? I know it is possible to remove it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The image file is stored in Macintosh-HD:Library:Caches:

There will only be like 3 files there so it should be easy to find.

You can take this file and edit it in an image editor such as GIMP(free) or Photoshop(not free) etc.

Don't forget to make sure that the image keeps it's name or OSX will get confused.

You may also need to use the original image, if, you want to blur it down.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It changes on boot but reverts back to default once I lock the screen again.

Comment: When I logout it shows the new image as well, it changes everything but the normal lock screen.